# How can I speed up my users’ required Video Uploads to improve their Onboarding Experience (on smartphones)?

Tags: video, file-upload, image-uploading, transloadit

Rookie poster here.  Grateful for any coaching: I’m coding my responsive web site on Cloud 9, using a Parse back end and DB.  A required step in my Sign Up process (on smartphones only) is for users to upload a 1 minute video of themselves, but handling data uploads over a cell network can be slow, and I need a way to do it reliably using html/js. What can I do to improve upload speed?  Should I suggest they only Sign Up when they’re connected to WiFi, rather than phone service?  Has anybody tried TransLoadit?  Thanks for your thoughts, David

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer this in bird's-eye view much like the questions are formulated. Disclaimer: I co-founded Transloadit and the `transloadit` tag got my attention.

Resumable uploads would be nice here. With that, a phone switches celltowers, or to wifi, or the user enters a tunnel or basement, the upload can just continue where it left off, afterwards. Speaking as a Transloadit cofounder, we're currently working on finalizing an open protocol for this over at http://tus.io, we'll then integrate that back into our service. Besides resumable uploads you would also profit from our distributed platform, meaning someone in Amsterdam will actually be uploading to Ireland, not Virginia.

If you're in a hurry though, you might be better off giving S3 resumable uploads a shot. Again: having a bucket per region would help a lot with speed for your end users. Route 53 offers ways to geographically loadbalance. Although I believe it works in chunks of 5MB minimum, videos from your example will probably quickly reach hundreds of MBs, depending on what audience you're targeting and how high-end their phones/tablets typically are.

One thing to consider, with operators getting more greedy about the bandwidth as that's what remains of their business models - and users typically having 1000MB or less per month at their disposal, do you want them to spend half of that on signing up for your service?

A wifi-only, opt-in, after-signup strategy might be the friendly approach. Without knowing your app, lowering the barrier to signup is generally a good idea.